# android - sharing an object in memory

Tags: android, shared-memory

Is it possible to instantiate an object in memory and keep it sharable for 2 or more processes in android? Say I create a `Calculator` class, I want to be able to access all of it's methods, variables etc. from 2 processes(a foreground activity and a background service). I also should be able to write to its class variables etc. Please tell me if there is any mechanism to do this.

Comment: have u checked sharedpreferences

Comment: @aryanagarwal , it doesn't seem what I was looking for particularly, because the object is something I will continuously access(the page says that this sharedPreference is expensive)

Comment: Just a thought ! You can save it in the file then

Comment: @aryanagarwal, it's probably a slow operation since needing IO to storage. But, for objects that require certain context and that don't just store some calculated values, I wonder if this is possible. E.g. the object at hand requires reference to the current activity, if I write that to a file, when I read it again, would it reference the same activity?

Comment: if you have created that object inside that activity, I think you should be able to do so

Comment: hm... it might be possible but still I wanted an in-memory solution. I was looking at this class: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/SharedMemory but not much information in the internet at all. Not very good explanations. do you know something about this,it sort of rings a bell but I can't fullly catch it

Comment: Just a thought.. can't you achieve your purpose using static fields and methods?

Comment: @Imal , statics don't work when the working in between two processes